# Is it ethical for an android application to check if its rival application is also installed by the user?

Tags: android, ethics, applications

I was just going through a food delivery application's preferences file where I found that it had a boolean to check if the user has one of its rival's app installed or not. Is it ethical to do so on their part?

Comment: I don't think we can discuss ethics here. But you might try ask law stackexchange if it is legal according to android's EULA.

Comment: Is it not a valid question for this platform? I am not an android dev but just curious. I already have a downvote before the answer.

Comment: The downvote is probably because the question is subjective. I wouldn't worry about it much, but see here if you are curious: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what they do with that information. If they purely use it to have a statistic "X% of our users also have the app from competitor Y installed" then I don't see anything wrong with it.

If they use it to skew the competition, e.g. by offering such users special discounts, I would counsider it unethical.

Comment: And of course, if it interferes with the rival application in any way, it's most definitely unethical, and probably illegal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: illegal under GDPR unless you have ticked a box allowing them to gather it surely

Comment: @Ewan: IANAL, but the GDPR does not apply for data that is not directly or indirectly linked to specific people, so if you collect purely aggregate data you're fine. https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/the-gdpr-what-exactly-is-personal-data

Comment: in this case though you would be collecting data about what apps i have on my phone

Comment: @Ewan: which is fine if I can't connect this data to you, because then it's not considered "personal data" Read the article I linked to.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I think that's very thin ice, the information sent from the phone will undoubtedly be identifiable via ip address. If you forget that info once it gets to you then its great for the next person in line, but it doesnt get you off the hook for the collection.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt in fact, you could argue that we needn't even consider the off device processing. Running the program on the device is processing personal data

Comment: @Ewan: Nope, I am very sure you are wrong in both regards. Your first argument would make it illegal to transmit any data whatsoever over the internet, and your second argument would make it illegal to distribute any installable software whatsoever. The GDPR is in parts impractical, but it is not *that* impractical.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Well, we will only know after its been tested in court. I'm surprised by you view though. Just because you forget my name, doesn't mean you catalogue all the files on my computer for your database without permission.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Ewan is right. GDPR is at its core about explicit consent of the user to allow getting tracked, in any way possible. Yes this is impractical, this is a nightmare for our devs to the design team, but as long as a user did not tick a box to accept being tracked in the way described along that box, you cannot track him. The anonymity you're talking about comes afterwards when someone wants to be erased from your database. Now you can anonymize him/erase his personal infos but keep the stats for convenience.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: I hate repeating myself, but you are very clearly wrong, do read the article I linked to.

Comment: @Ewan: And again, read the article. "all the files on my computer" is clearly personal data, especially taken together. The fact that you have one particular app installed is not. The GDPR *specifically* makes a difference between individual pieces of data that can be non-personal and collections of such pieces that together become personal since they allow identifying individuals.

Comment: @michael im sure weve all been on a million and one GDPR training courses by now. Untill its tested in court we wont really know where the dividing line lies

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the security of the operating system is broken. An app should not be able to find out what other applications are running on your device.

Comment: Not necessarily, an app should be able to find dependencies.

Comment: @gnasher729 the androd api to find the intent of a matching activity that (... add condifiont here ...) is not protected by android. matching can mean "can handle *.txt files" or "full activity class name = name of copetitor activity"

Answer (score 0):

I assume checking itself is not a problem yet.
I remember the news that some  big company was caught on making discounts when rival app was installed.
This information can be sent to the server as a part of some statistics call and the server can theoretically implement any logic it wants. I also assume that this logic will be immediately disabled if someone pays much attention.

Comment: what does this add that the accepted answer doesn't say?

Answer (score -2):

"It seems like X is not the default browser, would you like to make X the default?"

Comment: That's a config users have a hard time tracking down, and it is both common to want to do it, defer a decision, or definitely decline. But it's not actually about any other app, it's about whether your own should take the spot.